# What is the meaning of "Number of Cycles" in the FFT analysis tool

Tags: matlab, fft, simulink, frequency-analysis

Can someone please explain me the significance of the value in that marked textbox which says **Number of Cycles**, I have seen increasing the number of cycles increases resolution of FFT.

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://dsp.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

It means the number of cycles that FFT is going to analyse. Note that

```
 cycle time = 1/fundamental frequency
```

So if you want to analyse `t` time of signal then,

```
number of cycle = t/cycle time
```